# iBooks titles do not show in iTunes

Tags: itunes, books

I'm on the latest OS X, iBooks and iTunes. Have 20+ titles in eBooks, most of them added manually as PDFs or ePubs, only 3 bought from Apple.

When I connect my iPhone 6, and go to the sync option in iTunes, it shows me only the 3 titles I have purchased from the Store.[image: iTunes screenshot]

Thing is, it used to work perhaps a year ago, when I last paid attention. I still have an old iPad on which I have all the 20+ titles synced correctly. But obviously one of the updates since had broken things.

Tried to google for solutions, only to find people reporting the same problems on Apple Support forums, without answers. Any ideas how could one start to even debug the problem?

Comment: If you click on Selected books, does the display change at all? Probably not very likely, but it not be refreshing the display since you have "all" enabled.

Comment: Nope, nothing changes. Display does not seem to be refreshed at all.